# change location of scalebar of ggsn package in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, position

I wanna move scalebar in my plot in r. `scalebar(location=bottomright)` allows to control the position, but I need to move it from top right to **a little upper** place. is there any way to do it? scalebar is loaded from ggsn package in r

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can control the exact position of the scale bar using the `anchor` argument. By default, when you select `location = "topright"`, the top right hand corner of the scale bar is placed at the top right corner of the map's bounding box. You can specify the exact x and y co-ordinates of the top-right corner of the scale bar in a vector passed to `anchor`.

If we use an example from the `ggsn` package:

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.1, GDAL 3.2.1, PROJ 7.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(ggsn)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
#> Loading required package: grid

data(domestic_violence)

domestic_violence <- st_transform(domestic_violence, 4326)

p <- ggplot(domestic_violence, aes(fill = Scaled)) +
  geom_sf() +
  blank() +
  scale_fill_continuous(low = "#fff7ec", high = "#7F0000")
```

Let us draw the scale bar at the top right:

```
p + scalebar(domestic_violence, dist = 4, dist_unit = "km",
             transform = TRUE, model = "WGS84",
             location = "topright")
```

[image]

If we want to move it a bit to the West, we simply do:

```r
p + scalebar(domestic_violence, dist = 4, dist_unit = "km",
             transform = TRUE, model = "WGS84",
             location = "topright",
             anchor = c(x = -46.65, y = -23.3563))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>